# Passing the value to another page using ajax or localstorage in rails

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and I have a very noob question. I have a list of checkbox inputs in the **page A** and once some of the checkbox inputs are selected, I want to pass the checked values(id), to **page B**.

In the **Page B**, the list of checkbox inputs will be displaying but if some of them are checked in **Page A**, I want them hide it. Is there any best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
---Model
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}-->


C#:Controller: PageA and PageB Code:
 public ActionResult PageA()
    {
var modelist = GetModelList(new List<Customer>());
        return View(modelist);
    }



        public ActionResult PageB(string[] id)
    {
        var modelist = GetModelList(new List<Customer>());
        if (id != null)
        {
            modelist = modelist.Where(x => id[0].Split(',').ToList().Contains(x.CustomerID)).ToList();
        }
        return View(modelist);
    }
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $(".checkBox").prop('checked',
                $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
        var selectedIDs1 = '';
        $("#SelectId").click(function () {
            var selectedIDs = new Array();
            $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            window.location = "/home/PageB/?id=" + selectedIDs;
 

        });
    });
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>List of Customers Page A</h1>
    <input type="button" id="SelectId" value="Selected Customers Call to Page B" />
    <br />

    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /></th>
            <th>CustomerID</th>
            <th>CompanyName</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox"  value="@item.CustomerID" /></td>
                <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
                <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
                <td>@item.Country</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>List of Customers Page B</h1>
    
    <br />
    <br />
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /></th>
            <th>CustomerID</th>
            <th>CompanyName</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox"  value="@item.CustomerID" /></td>
                <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
                <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
                <td>@item.Country</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
```